# PHP regex splitting a string into two

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to split

```
EQUAL(title, "Alphabet"),EQUAL(content, "A, B") )
```

into an array

```
[EQUAL(title, "Alphabet"), EQUAL(content, "A, B")]
```

All I have managed to do was pick up the entire string. My regexp:

```
EQUAL\s*\(.+,\s*"?.+"?\)
```

Here is my Regex101 https://regex101.com/r/bImYwM/1/.

Any help would be great.

Comment: `\bEQUAL\s*\([^,)]+(?:,\s*[^,)]+)+\)`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/9clSRD/1

Comment: Your quantifiers are greedy. But you really should use negated character class to find non-`)`s, as @AhmedAbdelhameed has suggested. (e.g. could be done with https://regex101.com/r/bImYwM/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could match any char except `,` for the first part and any char except a `"` between the double quotes for the second part using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) which starts with `[^`

```
\bEQUAL\s*\([^,]+,\s*"[^"]+"\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1gZb00/1)

---

Note that currently using `\s*` and the negated character class, the pattern can also span newlines as `\s` also matches a newline and the negated character class matches any char except for the listed.

If there should only be a match on the same line, you can exclude matching the newlines from the negated character class and use `\h` to match a horizontal whitespace char.

```
\bEQUAL\h*\([^,\r\n]+,\h*"[^"\r\n]+"\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FG62YT/1)